# A Friend member Function can be used in separated files?

Tags: c++, makefile, friend, friend-function

I am reading C++ Primer and I´m stuck at

**7.3.4. Friendship Revisited** Making A Member Function a Friend

> Exercise 7.32: Define your own versions of Screen and Window_mgr in which
>   clear is a member of Window_mgr and a friend of Screen

I have found several solved exercises but in just one file as it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::ostream;

class Screen;

class Window_mgr{
public:
    using ScreenIndex = vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(ScreenIndex i);
private:
    vector<Screen> screens;
};

class Screen{
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);
public:
    typedef string::size_type   pos;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) {}

private:
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    string contents;
};

void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex i){
    Screen &s = screens[i];
    s.contents = string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}

int main(){
    Window_mgr var;
    return 0;
}
```

And I am trying to solve it in 5 separated files as main.cpp, Window_mgr.h, Window_mgr.cpp, Screen.h, and Screen.cpp; still without luck.
I have researched here in stackoverflow about this exercise, and i have found a lot, but anything about compile it in separates files so i am thinking...

> Friend member functions have to be compile in the same file?

if not

> How can this be done separating each class in it own file separating implementation and interface?
>
> > - main.cpp
> > - Screen.h/Screen.cpp
> > - Window_mgr.h/Window_mgr.cpp

and

> Optional: In What order(How) this 5 files must be compile in a `makefile`

This can be posible?
Thanks!

Comment: _Friend member functions have to be compile in the same file?_ No.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is circular reference, if you solve it by 5 separated files, the Screen.h

```
#ifndef __SRCEEN__
#define __SRCEEN__
#include <string>
#include "window_mgr.h"
using namespace std;
class Screen{
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);// need Window_mgr defination
public:
    typedef string::size_type pos;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c) : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) {}

private:
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    string contents;
};
#endif
```

your window_mgr.h

```
#ifndef __WINDOW_MGR__
#define __WINDOW_MGR__
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Screen.h"
using namespace std;
class Screen;
class Window_mgr{
public:
   using ScreenIndex = vector<Screen>::size_type;// need Screen defination
   void clear(size_t i);
private:
   vector<Screen> screens;// need Screen defination
};
#endif
```

they need to get the definition of each other, you can use forward declaration to solve it in single file, but it seems not a good solution for this situation:(